# OpenAI API query local PDF slow

Tags: openai-api

I'm using lanchain text splitter to split the document and store using ChromaDb, I set the chunk size 1000.  When using openai api to query the document, it response very slow.  The model I use is GPT-4, temperature 0.9, max_tokens set to 2000.  When query, I load the vector store using code below

```
vectorstore = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, 
collection_name=collection_name,
                 embedding_function=embeddings)
vectorstore_retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 3})
```

Query the store

```
  relevant_docs = vectorstore_retriever.get_relevant_documents(transcript["text"])

        # Use the provided function to prepare the context
        context = get_page_contents(relevant_docs)

        # Prepare the prompt for GPT-3.5-turbo with the context
        query_with_context = human_template.format(query=transcript["text"], context=context)

        messages.append({"role": "user", "content": query_with_context})
        print(query_with_context)
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            messages=messages,
            temperature=0.9,
            max_tokens=2000
        )
```

I'm using Gradio interface and audio to record the voice and convert it to text.

Any idea what's wrong?  The response is very slow, around 15second above.